# How to print text of all loc tags using casperjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, slimerjs

I need to extract loc tags text of entire page and get the count of all extracted text .Iterate in a loop for following command casper.open('http://www.raybiztech.com/.....') for different iterations. Can any one help for the above scenario

```
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
        <url>
            <loc>http://raybiztech.com/blog</loc>
            <lastmod>2014-02-24</lastmod>
        </url><url>
            <loc>http://raybiztech.com/blog/application-development-maintenance</loc>
            <lastmod>2014-02-14</lastmod>
        </url><url>
            <loc>http://raybiztech.com/blog/application-development-maintenance/analysis-services-testing-with-nick</loc>
            <lastmod>2014-02-14</lastmod>
        </url><url>
            <loc>http://raybiztech.com/blog/application-development-maintenance/bi-solution-join-on-premises-to-windows-azure</loc>
            <lastmod>2014-02-14</lastmod>
        </url><url>
            <loc>http://raybiztech.com/blog/application-development-maintenance/data-profiling-im-data-source-view</loc>
            <lastmod>2014-02-14</lastmod>
        </url><url>
            <loc>http://raybiztech.com/blog/application-development-maintenance/data-programmability-tools-with-craig-lee</loc>
            <lastmod>2014-02-14</lastmod>
 .....
```

I updated the code as below.I want extract text in particular "loc" and iterate in casper.thenopen("http://raybiztech.com/blog");

```
var casper = new require('casper').Casper({
    verbose: true,          // log messages will be printed out to the console
    logLevel: "debug",              // "Debug" level messages will be logged        
    safeLogs: false,


});
    var fs = require('fs');
        var fname = new Date().getTime() + '.xml';
    var save = fs.pathJoin(fs.workingDirectory, 'raybiztech', fname);

casper.test.begin('Payment Gateway',function(test) {

/*
 * Start the browser with url http://lcdev.bluemodus.com/
 */
casper.start('http://www.raybiztech.com/sitemap.xml',function(){
    this.capture('/home/gopi/output/learningcounts/cmsHome.jpg');
    this.echo(this.getCurrentUrl());
    fs.write(save, this.getPageContent() + '\n', 'w');
    require('utils').dump(this.getElementsInfo('loc'));


});
casper.viewport(1366,768);
casper.run(function() {
    test.done();
    casper.test.renderResults(true, 0, '/home/gopi/workspace/learningcounts/raybiztech.xml');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [`casper.getElementsInfo`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#getelementsinfo) returns an array with every item containing the `text` property. You can then iterate over the array with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap) to transform the objects to the `text` property string.

Comment: I didn't provide code, because it is a really easy to do this with the pointers given.

Comment: And what is the problem with the above code? Please don't edit your question after you get an answer.